# Run Bash script on selected files in Finder

Tags: bash, macos, shell, finder

I have a tiny Bash script that executes ffmpeg and a touch command on an input file. I use this to recompress video files from my camera. I would like to be able to right-click files in Finder and run the script on the select file(s), preferably showing the terminal window while executing and closing when done.

How to do this on macOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. I started **Automator** by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> and starting to type `"Automator"`, hitting <kbd>↩</kbd> as soon as it guessed correctly. I then created a *"Quick Action"* that contains this code:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    repeat with theItem in input
        set f to POSIX path of theItem
        tell application "Terminal"
            activate
            tell window 1
                do script "echo " & f
            end tell
        end tell
    end repeat
end run
```

and looks like this:

[image]

It basically just `echo`s the filename, but you can put `ffmpeg` commands in there instead.

Comment: You are probably right this is the way to do it. I was hoping there was something even simpler I didn't see.

Comment: I ended up doing it like this, though using AppleScript to call into Bash seems like one layer too many.

Comment: You could equally start from `bash` and use `osascript` to get a list of selected items from the Finder. Note you could also add `&` to the end of the `ffmpeg` commands to get them done faster in parallel, by the way.

Answer (score -1):

Why using finder? Or automator? Or going though loops and hoops just to use the GUI?

You have fully-functional bash shell in MacOS, so save time and hassle with the below one-liner.

Assuming you need to run your script for all *.mpeg files in the folder.

Try this:

```
ls *mpeg | xargs <your_script_name>
```

You will see the execution output in the same terminal window.

Comment: Whilst I agree that you have a fully functional bash shell in macOS, many folk have no desire to type commands into a Terminal and own their Macs for years without ever doing so...

Comment: Granted, but the dude has already written his Bash script. Why not just run it from there too?